# tengo problemas con conectarme a la DB en

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, asp.net

Pasa que estoy haciendo un proyecto en C#, asp.net ya cree las masterpage y configure el webconfig, a la masterpage en  también lo modifique de esta forma

```
public partial class Mestra : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

    static string cadenaconexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CadenaConexion"].ConnectionString;

    public static string CadenaConexion
    {
        get { return cadenaconexion; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (!IsPostBack)
        {


        }
```

pero al momento de MantencionLibros.aspx.cs me encuentro con que strign CadenaConexion = MasterPage.CadenaConexion Me sale en rojo la parte de
MasterPage.CadenaConexion<---

```
  public partial class MantencionLibros : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Decimal code;
    string libro;
    string CadenaConexion = MasterPage.CadenaConexion;
```

las referencias están listas pero la verdad no se que pasa.
Se agradece un monton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu master page, tienes esto

```
static string cadenaconexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CadenaConexion"].ConnectionString;
```

Debes cambiarlo por esto

```
public static string cadenaconexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CadenaConexion"].ConnectionString;
```

En el primer caso tienes una variable privada (que es la opción por defecto si es que no colocas nada), no puedes acceder a una variable privada desde otra clase. Debes agregar que sea publica

Comment: Muchas Gracias estaba atrapado y me salvaste 10/10